# populate selected options dynamically in multiselect dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a multi-select drop-down list with a checkbox  which will allow a user to select multiple options without pressing command/ctrl buttons  please help on this

```
<select id='testSelect2' name="test" multiple>

<option value='1'> sunday</option >
<option value='2'> monday</option>
<option value='3'> tuesday</option>
<option value='4'> wensday</option>
<option value='5'> thrusday</option>
<option value='6'>friday </option>
<option value='7'>saturday </option>
</select>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEoS4.png)

Comment: maybe a jquery plugin for multiple options dropdown will help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, you can use this plug in http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/

If you want to do this with vanilla javascript, you may try to handle click event on options and achieve this behaviour manually.